# Module "MyApp" not found in UnitTest-Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, swift3, xcode7

Im trying to test some Swift class (@objc class) in my legacy Objc code. I am importing "UnitTests-Swift.h" in my test classes.

Then I get this error:

> Module "MyApp" not found in the autogenerated "UnitTests-Swift.h"

This is whats inside the top part of the "UnitTests-Swift.h"

```
typedef int swift_int3  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(3)));
typedef int swift_int4  __attribute__((__ext_vector_type__(4)));
#if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(modules)
@import XCTest;
@import ObjectiveC;
@import MyApp;
@import CoreData;
#endif
```

I cleaned the project, checked all the relevant flags (["No such module" when using @testable in Xcode Unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008403/no-such-module-when-using-testable-in-xcode-unit-tests), [Can't use Swift classes inside Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206732/cant-use-swift-classes-inside-objective-c)), removed derived data and so on.. No idea of whats happening, but I m quite sure that @import MyApp shouldnt be there..

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I'm having this problem too.

Comment: By request, I've filed this in the Swift bugs database: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3381

Comment: Is this something that can be reproduced in Xcode 7, or does it require an obj-c project made with an older version? Can you provide steps to reproduce from scratch?

Comment: do swift & objective-C classes are in the same target ?

Answer (score 8):

Just got this issue in my project and after the entire day spent on investigation I finally resolved it.
Basically this happens because you have cyclic dependency between ObjC and Swift. So in my case it was:

- Swift Protocol with `@obj` attribute in a main target;
- Swift Class in UnitTest target which inherited this Protocol;
- Import `UnitTestTarget-Swift.h` in any Objective-C class of your UnitTest target

So fairly simple combination leads to this error. In order to fix this you want either:

- simply make sure that your Swift Class in UnitTest target is `private`, so it won't get to `UnitTestTarget-Swift.h`

or

- do not mark your original Swift Protocol as `@objc`, which will allow you to access your SwiftClass from all ObjectiveC test classes, but those classes won't have any idea about the Swift Protocol.

Answer (score 1):

This solution helped me:

1. Open **Tests Target Build Settings**
2. Search for `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS`
3. In the line called "Header Search Paths" set value `$CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR/myProjectName.build/DerivedSources`
4. Clean and Cmd+U again

Hope it helps!

Many thanks to this [article](https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/ios-tests-working-with-objective-c-and-swift-class-together-aaf40f91a27c).

Answer (score 0):

Because the Swift class to be tested is part of MyApp, you should be importing "MyApp-Swift.h" in the test classes instead of "UnitTests-Swift.h".

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Swift unit test (just create a new unit file and change the extension by `.swift`).

From that unit test file you can use your Swift classes.

And you can also import that file from your Objective-C unit tests (and the other way around) using the test module bridging headers.

And this would be the default example for your Swift unit test file:

```
import XCTest
@testable import MyApp

class MyAppSwiftTests: XCTestCase {

  override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
  }

  override func tearDown() {
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    super.tearDown()
  }

  func testExample() {
    // This is an example of a functional test case.
    // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.
  }

  func testPerformanceExample() {

    // This is an example of a performance test case.
    self.measure {
      // Put the code you want to measure the time of here.
    }
  }
}
```