# Module not found error in file "AppName-Swift.h" when running unit test target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing

My iOS project name is "A". One of its targets is named "B". This project also has the unit test target. I set B as `Host Application` in unit test target and use `@testable import B` in swift test files in order to have access to files in target B.

The unit test target also has test files written in objc. One test file written in objc imported `A-Swift.h` file. When I start to build the unit test target, the generated `A-Swift.h` file has an error that module 'B' not found.
[image]

Did anyone face similar issue before? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52905896/5617142) works for me! Hope it can help you if you are facing the similar issue.