# No such module <product module name> in XCode Unit test

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, unit-testing, compilation

I have a mixed objective-c and Swift project and I try to write Unit tests for it.
My project name is: Alphaproject
my product module name is: Alphaproject
I set to YES Defines Module in my main Target (Alphaproject)
and set to YES EnableTestability for Debug only in this same Target.

In my Test class, I try to import my product module name:

@testable import Alphaproject

Additional notes:

- all my projects files are only part of the main target
- my test files are only part of the test target
- My scheme for Test is set to Build Debug configuration.
- I also tried to clean the Build folder (ALT + Clean)
- The project doesn't have any error when compiling or trying to run tests except this "No such module Alphaproject"

Any other ideas?

Comment: I was having this same issue, but the problem was resolved after going to Build Settings and setting "Defines Modules" = YES under the main main target and testing target.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK! The problem was coming from the fact that I had arm64 in my Debug configuration for Valid Architectures.
As the main target also doesn't contain arm64 in Valid Architectures, It couldn't apparently find the module...
I think apple can make better work on displaying a proper error here. (Apple, if you read me, please)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the initial Xcode project was Objective-C, and I added testing targets that were Swift-based, and the `import <Product Moodule Name>` failed. I ensured that `Defines Module` was set to `YES` in Build Settings, but still got the error as indicated. The fix for me was to add a Bridging Header into the Objective-C main project.