# Xcode 8.1 No such module 'Foo' from unit tests

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, xcode8

I upgraded from Xcode 7.3.1 to Xcode 8.1 and chose Swift 2.3 migration. Now my unit tests won't compile, it fails on the `import`, specifically `No such module 'Foo'` where Foo is the module name.

"Enable Testability" is already set to Yes. I have "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" set to Yes for both the project and target. I've tried clean, delete DerivedData and rebuild.

Comment: As a last resort you could start a fresh project (rather than the migration), and then copy in your classes one by one. Make sure that all the bugs are fixed in every class. When I migrated over, I recall that there were some things that couldn't be automatically converted. Add the Unit Tests last.