# Call Function in Main Target From Test Target in Xcode(swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, uitest

I am writing UITest for my app. In some parts of the UITest, I should call functions from Main target. When I create an Object from the Class(that has the implementation of the function), I get the error "use of undeclared of type CLASSNAME". I added the Class to the Compile Source of the test target.Then I get the same error but this time for the super class.
I added Classes to the compile source again and again, till I get this error  "use of undeclared of UITextField, UIColor."
UITextField and UIColor are part of UIkit, then I import UIkit to my test Class , but did not work.
Any idea how to solve it?
In generell, How should we call functions in main target from test target?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Add @Testable in front of your main Class/Method in your main target. 
See also https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html

Comment: I did use testable. But also get error Mach O linker. I also tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008403/no-such-module-when-using-testable-in-xcode-unit-tests/32844977#32844977 , but could not fix it.

Comment: Can you add your error message log ?

Answer (score 0):

import your target with @testable import

```
import XCTest
@testable import MyProject
```

Comment: I did use testable. But also get error Mach O linker.i also tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008403/no-such-module-when-using-testable-in-xcode-unit-tests/32844977#32844977 , but could not fix it.