# How to make an Objective-C only target build a module?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm trying to add Swift unit tests to an all Objective-C based project. If I attempt to test the code the build will fail with the following error:

```
 @testable import Foo   // No such module 'Foo'
```

However, if I add a Swift file to the Foo target, the unit tests will build and run correctly, so it seems Xcode will only generate the Foo module if there is a Swift file in it. How can I force Xcode to create a module when it doesn't include a Swift file? (I'd like to avoid having the unnecessary Swift file if possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem is using the `@testable import Foo`. Simply removing the line allows the unit tests to build and run.