# Test object state during UI testing (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, testing, xcode-ui-testing

Is it possible to test object state (global variable, singleton object) during UI test? For example, I have UI test where some buttons were tapped and text entered to a textfield. I want to assert that object state changes correctly based on user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to access variables from your application's code during a UI test. Your app and the UI tests run in separate executables and don't have access to each others' internals at runtime.

To check the state of your text fields, you'll need to either read the state from the XCUIElement representing the text field (if the state you're interested in is visible in the UI) or write a unit test to check the state.

From Apple (via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32039868/5052894)):

> UI tests execute differently from Unit tests - Unit tests run inside your application process so they can access your application code. UI tests execute in a separate process, outside your application, so they can simulate how the user interacts with the application. It’s not expected that you will be able to access your app class from a UI test.

Comment: Thanks for clarification!